# How to find the parent of an element by it's class name and add CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, class, parent, closest

I have an HTML element with a class and want to add simple CSS, or better a class, to it's direct parent.

I added a custom list-style-type (blue checkmarks) to a list. Since the default type="disc" is still in place (so discs and checkmarks are displayed next to each other), I want to remove the discs with jQuery.

I work on a page in WordPress and make the notation in the file:
root/wp-content/themes/my_theme/assets/js/main.js

I also tried noting it down in:
root/wp-content/themes/my_theme/assets/js/theme-custom.js (which is a .js-file that came with the theme)

My HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="classname_a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></li>
  <li><span class="classname_a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></li>
  <li><span class="classname_a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></li>
  <li><span class="classname_a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Some of my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span.classname_a").parent().css("list-style-type": "none", "margin-left": "-20px");
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span.classname_a").parent("li").addClass("test");
});
```

Comment: Your `css()` call doesn't work because you need to use an object when supplying multiple parameters - https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/69dt37wr/. Your second example works fine, though - https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/h7rLxt6y/, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: use `closest('ul')` instead of `parent('li')`

Comment: Open your developer tools and go to the console, and make sure you are not encountering any errors.  Wordpress commonly runs jQuery in noConflict mode, so `$` may not be jQuery

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef why? The OP wants to add the class to the `li`, and `parent('li')` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I know but in his `.css` he trying to use `list-style-type` so I think he need to know that the `list-style-type` is for `<ul>` not for `<li>` .. I know in his second example the `.addClass` will work correctly

Comment: So the issue is it's not working because OP is appling `ul` styles to an `li` instead of the `ul` (along with wrong method signature as already advised).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: thanks a lot, indeed the second example at least works. Maybe I'm noting it down in the wrong file?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef: actually it works with the css addressed to the `li`

Comment: @Taplar: no errors, already checked for that; how else can I note down the code if Wordpress doesn't like the `$` ?

Comment: Yes @Xandru my first time to know that `list-of-type` works with `<li>`. thanks

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for the late reply. Just letting you know that I've added the code directly in the backend of the theme in a "Custom JS" editor. Not the way I wanted to do it, but it works at least. Thanks for all the help though!